# realizar un if de transform: translate3d

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transform

Tengo que realizar una funcionalidad a un plugin de carousel. 
Como hago para escribir un if que detecte si un div tiene el estilo "transform" menor a "translate3d(-650px, 0, 0)". Puede que ser con javascript o jquery.

```
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 1055px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Daijard, sin código es muy difícil poderte ayudar, debes mostrarnos por lo menos el código que has intentado hacer y en caso de haber errores en consola también debes mostrarlos, **es importante que leas [ask]**...saludos !

Comment: Hola Camilo. Es que no se bien como seria la sintaxis del if. El div seria asi:<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 1055px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;"></div>. Sea para este caso o para algun otro no se como escribir el condicional que detecte el translate3d. No encontre ningun ejemplo sencillo en internet.

Answer (score 2):

Con jquery puedes validar el valor que tiene la propiedad mas no he probado si se pueda validar el valor con los pixeles exactos, si pones tu código con el que necesitas realizar la acción tal vez pueda probar pero puedes intentar tu, la manera para validar es con el metodo .css(), la estructura seria asi:

```js
if ($("#id_div").css("propiedad") == "valor_propiedad"){

/* ejecutar si */

}else{

/* ejecutar si no */
}
```

Comment: Si, ya he probado asi pero no me llega al console.log. No entiende el condicional escrito de esta manera. if ($(".owl-stage").css("transform") == "translate3d(-650px, 0px, 0px)"){
                        console.log("hola");
                      }

Comment: Ya sacaste una consola de $(".owl-stage").css("transform") para ver si realmente te trae translate3d(-650px, 0px, 0px) ??